# Trying to get my first FullCalendar to work

Tags: javascript, html, fullcalendar

I have just started trying to implement FullCalendar; however, my display is blank with no error messages on the console log or logs. What have I not included please?

HTML:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
    var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
      initialView: 'resourceTimelineWeek'
    });
    calendar.render();
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/5.0.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link href='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fullcalendar@5.10.1/main.min.css' rel='stylesheet' />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/5.0.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fullcalendar@5.10.1/main.min.js"></script>
<div id='calendar'></div>
```

Comment: You should use EITHER `$(document).ready` or `window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded`, not both together.  By the time the document is ready, the window had already loaded the DOM content, so it never fires.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You add an event listener to `DOMContentLoaded` on jQuery's `$(document).ready()`. At that time `DOMContentLoaded` has already happened, so the listener you attach to `DOMContentLoaded` never executes.

Use either of the two, not both.

Second mistake is you are loading the wrong fullCalendar script. To use "resourceTimelineWeek" you need to include `<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fullcalendar-scheduler@5.10.1/main.min.js"></script>` (and also the corresponding CSS).

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  const calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(document.getElementById('calendar'), {
    initialView: 'resourceTimelineWeek'
  });
  calendar.render();
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/5.0.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fullcalendar-scheduler@5.10.1/main.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/5.0.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fullcalendar-scheduler@5.10.1/main.min.js"></script>
<div id='calendar'></div>
```